# UIScrollview setContentOffset and animation

Tags: uiscrollview, core-animation

I want to `setContentOffset` with different animation transition.

Now I use:

```
[UIScrollView animateWithDuration:speed animations:^ {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset];
}];
```

Can you help me, How I achieve animation during set offset.

Comment: view My answer it may be helpful to you .just need to change little bit according your requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974579/scroll-view-issues-when-key-board-moves-up-in-uitextfield-textview-iphone/12974850#12974850

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, I understand what you are looking for. However, in the case you are looking for a `UIScrollView` class whose `contentOffset` is animated with a non-linear timing function you might take a like at my [MOScrollView](https://github.com/plancalculus/MOScrollView). I use a `CADisplayLink` to animate the `contentOffset`. Though, please note that it might not work perfectly as I did not yet use this class in production.